# MySql all rows that has a specific relation or does not have any relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

im doing a complex query between two tables. I need the rows that has a specific relation and those that does not.

For example:

Element

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         c        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Element attributes

```
|------------------|--------------------|
|    id_element    |      id_attribute  |
|------------------|--------------------|
|         1        |         55         |
|------------------|--------------------|
|         1        |         78         |
|------------------|--------------------|
|         3        |         55         |
|------------------|--------------------|
```

What i need is all the elements that does not have the attribute 78, so in this example it should output 2 and 3.

I tried with

```
SELECT *
FROM element
LEFT JOIN element_attributes
ON (element.id = element_attributes.id_element AND element_attributes.id_element != 78)
```

But for example, on element 1, it does the left join with the first attributes row and is 55, so it ends with the results and that is not the behaviour that im expecting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from element e
where not exists (select 1
                  from element_attributes ea
                  where ea.id_element = e.id and e.id_element = 78
                 );
```